# How to iterate nested JSON with ArangoDB?

Tags: json, arangodb, aql

I have JSON with next structure:
`[[{"QID":1,"AID":1},{"SubAID":[]}],[{"QID":2,"AID":1},{"SubAID":[2,4]}],[{"QID":3,"AID":1},{"SubAID":[]}],{"MaxArea":"90","MinArea":"16"}]`

Is this ok for ArangoDB? I tried to push it's with http-api (I don't have a driver for my language - D), but I got `error 500`, maybe I'm wrong, maybe this JSON is not correct for ArangoDB.

Also I would like to get any examples of iterating such JSON with AQL. For example if I need value of `SubAID` where `QID` is `2`, how should I write such query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the main level, documents in ArangoDB are JSON objects. The JSON you're showing above in a JSON array, so it won't be accepted as is as a document.

What you can do is wrap the above JSON in an object attribute, for example `data`:

`{"data":[[{"QID":1,"AID":1},{"SubAID":[]}],[{"QID":2,"AID":1},{"SubAID":[2,4]}],[{"QID":3,"AID":1},{"SubAID":[]}],{"MaxArea":"90","MinArea":"16"}]}`

Regarding querying the data: it looks like data is an array containing arrays and an object. Inside the arrays there is an object with attributes `QID` and `AID` at array position 0, and an object containing `SubAid` at array position 1.

If that's true for all data, the a query like as follows should find the documents that  a `QID` value of `2`:

```
/* iterate over all documents in collection */
FOR doc IN collection 

  LET s = (
    /* iterate over embedded attribute "data */
    FOR sub IN doc.data 

      /* look at QID at array position 0 */
      FILTER sub[0].QID == 2 

      /* first match is sufficient */
      LIMIT 1 

      /* return SubAID value from array position 1 */
      RETURN sub[1].SubAID 
  ) 

  /* only return documents with a match */
  FILTER LENGTH(s) > 0 

  /* return first result from subquery (subquery result is always an array) */
  RETURN s[0]
```